# Does Incremental Mariabackup backs up a specified database or every node's databases

Tags: backup, mariadb, mariadb-10.5

```
# Set the backup directory
        backup_dir="/mnt/nas/tmp-storage"

# Set the MySQL/MariaDB backup user and password
        backup_user="root"
        backup_password="admin"

# Set the current date
        current_date=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")


# Schedule incremental backups for every day at 00:00

       current_date=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
       yesterday=$(date -d "$current_date - 1 day" +"%Y-%m-%d")
 

      # while true; do
      # sleep $((24*60*60 - $(date +%s) % (24*60*60))) # Wait until midnight


# Check if incremental backup has been perforemd before, if not, perform incremental backup based on the full backup
  if [ ! -d "/mnt/nas/incr-backup" ]; then

       sudo mkdir -p /mnt/nas/incr-backup/bcs_01-$yesterday
        sudo docker exec mariadb  mariabackup --user="$backup_user" --password="$backup_password" --backup --target-dir=/backup  --incremental-basedir=/full-backup/bcs_01-$current_date   --no-lock  --databases bcs_01
        sudo find $backup_dir/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec mv -t /mnt/nas/incr-backup/bcs_01-$yesterday   {} +
       #tar czvf /mnt/nas/full-backup/bcs_01-$current_date.tar.gz /mnt/nas/full-backup/bcs_01-$yesterday --remove-files
  else
       sudo docker exec mariadb  mariabackup --user="$backup_user" --password="$backup_password" --backup --target-dir=/backup --incremental-basedir=/mnt/nas/incr-backup/bcs_01-$yesterday --no-lock
       sudo find $backup_dir/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec mv -t /mnt/nas/incr-backup/bcs_01-$current_date   {} +
       #tar czvf /mnt/nas/full-backup/bcs_01-$current_date.tar.gz /mnt/nas/inr-backup/bcs_01-$yesterday --remove-files
  fi
```

This is an excerpt of a bash script I developed , the first part, wich is the full backup is working fine but the incremental backup which pasted here tries to backup all the databases even though i specified only one database. Also `--incremental-basedir=/full-backup/bcs_01-$current_date` references a folder that contains the full backup of the database.

I wonder why it is backing up every database